# Import of assets is not resolving correctly, Do I need to do something extra?

Tags: import, path, jsx

So, as I was trying to work on the Navbar I faced an issue because, I need to import a NavLinks array, containing the text for the navLinks, which I created as an Array inside the index.js within a folder called "constants" inside the src.

this is how I imported it to the Navbar.jsx

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { navLinks } from "../constants";

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
  <div>home</div>  )
}

export default Navbar
```

and this is what my file index.js looks like.

```
import { agile, behanceLogo, design_minded_icon, discordLogo, envelopeIcon, girlDesk3D, githubLogo, sassLogo, cssLogo, htmlLogo, javascriptLogo, linkedInLogo, messageIcon, mongodbLogo, moonIcon, multiculturalIcon, nodejsLogo, paperplaneIcon, personIcon, profile_bewerbung_foto, reactLogo,typescript_logo, paperplaneIcon, backtoTop } from "../assets";

export const navLinks = [
    {
        id: "home",
        title: "Home",
    },
    {
        id: "work",
        title: "Work"
    },
    {
        id: "about",
        title: "About"
    },
    {
        id: "contact",
        title: "Contact"
    }
];

export const features = [
    {
        id: "feature-1",
        icon: agile,
        title: "Agile",
        content: "Experience with a methodology that emphasizes collaboration and continuous improvement.", 
    },
    {
        id: "feature-2",
        icon: design_minded_icon,
        title: "Design-minded",
        content: "The driving aspect for any of my designs has a start in the consideration of human interaction and focus on the design principles.", 
    },
    {
        id: "feature-3",
        icon: multiculturalIcon,
        title: "Multicultural",
        content: "I am an adaptable individual who has had experience working in a multicultural team.", 
    },
]

export const about = 
    {
        title: "about",
        parragraf1: "Hi there!  , My name is Nathalia Padron. I am originally from Caracas, Venezuela and I am currently based in Stuttgart, since 2016.",
        parragraf2: "Before making the leap into Front-end Design I studied Product Design in IDC ( Instituto de Diseno de Caracas ) and worked several years as a Grafic Designer in Germany and Venezuela.",
        parragraf3: "I feel comfortable working with CSS and JavaScript and I continue to learn React, I would love to extend my skillset to perform tasks related to UX/UI. Also, I have recently received a certification in MERN Stack and continue to learn and develop my understanding towards the backend.",
        recently: "Recently I have been working with the following technology Stack",
        logos: [
            htmlLogo,
            cssLogo,
            javascriptLogo,
            sassLogo,
            typescript_logo,
            reactLogo,
            nodejslogo,
            mongodbLogo,
        ],
    }

    export const technologieStack = [
        {
            title1: "Libraries & Frameworks",
            technologies: 
            [
                "Tailwind CSS",
                "Bootstrap",
                "Sass",
                "React",
            ]
        }, 
        {
            title2: "Design Tools",
            technologies: 
            [
                "GoogleFonts",
                "Figma",
                "Canva",
            ]
        },
        {
            title3: "Other Tools",
            technologies: 
            [
                "VS Code",
                "Git + Hub",
                "Azure DevOps",
                "Chrome Dev Tools",
            ]
        },
    ]
        
export const cards = [
    {
        name: "MLAY TOURS",
        content: "A MERN Stack project developed as a last project for a bootcamp I finished at DCI. Worked with a customer and developed brand identity.",
        link: "",
    }
]

export const contactForm = {
    parragraf1: "I'm interested in a position within a team environment in a Web Agency working on large and creative projects.",
    parragraf2: "However, if you have a request or question, don't hesitate to use this form.",
    inputs: [
        {
            name: "Full name",
            icon: personIcon,
        },
        {
            name: "E.g marcsummer@gmail.com",
            icon: envelopeIcon,
        },
        {
            name: "leave me a Message",
            icon: messageIcon,
        },
    ],
    sendbutton: "send",
    icon: paperplaneIcon,
}

export const footer = [
    {
        id: "social-media-1",
        icon: linkedInLogo,
        link: "",
    },
    {
        id: "social-media-2",
        icon: behanceLogo,
        link: "",
    },
    {
        id: "social-media-3",
        icon: githubLogo,
        link: "",
    },
    {
        id: "social-media-4",
        icon: discordLogo,
        link: "",
    },
    {
        id: "goTotop",
        icon: backtoTop,
        link: "",
    },
  ];
```

the app is crashing and says "Failed to resolve import "../assets" from "src/constants/index.js".

it's complaining because inside the index.js (where I created all the objects containing text and logos for the website) there is an import which is not resolving, the path to the "assets" folder is apparently wrong. I have checked the folder structure and it seems correct. The assets folder is on the same level as the components and constants folder inside the source. Do I need to do something extra to ensure that the images are being imported?

what I did was have all the pngs inside this assets folder and I am just writing the import in this way:

```
import { agile, behanceLogo, design_minded_icon, discordLogo, envelopeIcon, girlDesk3D, githubLogo, sassLogo, cssLogo, htmlLogo, javascriptLogo, linkedInLogo, messageIcon, mongodbLogo, moonIcon, multiculturalIcon, nodejsLogo, paperplaneIcon, personIcon, profile_bewerbung_foto, reactLogo,typescript_logo, paperplaneIcon, backtoTop } from "../assets";
```

the names provided inside the curly brackets are the names for each of the pngs

Comment: Maybe you can provide some screenshots of the actual folder structure. 
Additionally, it is helpful to know which dev-server / bundler you are using. How did you bootstrap the project? Using create-react-app or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look on your GitHub Profile made me find the [problematic repository](https://github.com/NattyDCI/portfolioFrontendDevNathaliaPadron/tree/main/portfolioFrontendNathalia/src/assets).

**Problem:** You are trying to import multiple files from a folder via named imports. Unfortunately, this is not how named imports work.

`import { ... } from "../assets"` tries to resolve an index file (`index.ts(x)` or `index.js(x)`), which is not present in that folder.
These files are also called barrel files. see: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/barrel

**Solution:**

Directly reference the image files you want to import via default imports
`import ReactLogo from "../assets/reactLogo.png"`

As an Alternative you could also provide an index file which re-exports the image files as a named export

```js
// assets/index.js

export { default as ReactLogo } from "./reactLogo.png";
export { default as TypeScriptLogo } from "./typescript_logo.png";


// index.js
import { ReactLogo, TypeScriptLogo } from "../assets"
```

Comment: I re exported the images in a new index file and is now working.